# compiling C++ unidentified symbols for architecture x86_64 in vector exercise

Tags: c++, function, vector, compiler-errors, linker-errors

(Updated with new code but same problem persists)

So doing some homework for my C++ class and almost finished but it just won't compile and spits back the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "reportNames(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >, char)", referenced from:
      _main in CHomeWork11-55ac9e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

the code for the program is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
ifstream fin;

int getRank(vector<string> names, string choice);
void reportNames(vector<string> names, char letter);

int main ()

{
  string name;
  int counter = 0;
  string choice;
  bool on = true;
  char letter;

 vector <string> names;
 vector <string>::iterator iter;
 vector <string>::iterator iterF;

    fin.open("GirlNames.txt");  // reads in data

    getline(fin, name);

    while (!fin.fail())
    {
          names.push_back(name);
          getline(fin, name);
    }
    fin.close();

    cout << "Top Ten Baby Girl Names:" << endl;

    iter = names.begin();

    while(counter !=10)
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
        iter++;
        counter++;
    }

    while(on)
    {
        cout << "Enter a name (press q to quit)" << endl;
        getline(cin, choice);
        if(choice == "q")
           on = false;

        else
        {
            iterF = find(names.begin(), names.end(), choice);
            if(iterF == names.end())
               cout << choice << " Is not on this list" << endl;
            else
            {
                  cout << choice << " is rank " << getRank(names, choice) << endl;
            }  
        }
    }
    sort(names.begin(), names.end());

    cout << "enter a starting letter for your name:" << endl;
    cin >> letter;
    reportNames(names, letter);
}

int getRank(vector<string> names, string choice)
{
    int rank = 1;
   for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
   {
       if(names[i] == choice)
           return rank;
        else
            rank++;
   }
   return 0; //dummy return statement for the compiler
}
void reportName(vector<string> names, char letter)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
   {
       if(names[i].find(letter) !=string::npos)
         cout << names[i] << endl;
   }

}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem has something to do with the reportName function as the code was compiling and running before I created it.

Comment: OT: you pass by value `vector<string> names` in many functions where you should pass by constant reference.

Answer (score 0):

Compare two lines:

```
void reportNames(vector<string> v, char letter);
void reportName(vector<string> names, char letter) {
...
```

You declared a function with one name but defined with another.

Comment: went back and changed that. Still spits back the same error

Comment: That should solve the issue. Have you saved the file? Please provide the updated code.

Comment: @RobertHebert, please read my answer carefully. There is no need to rename the parameters (the parameter names are not in the function signature). The name of the function itself is incorrect. You have plural `reportNames` in the declaration and single `reportName` in the definition. Count the number of characters in each name.

Comment: oh I see, I was so focused on the parameter names I didn't notice the actual function name typo. Really kicking myself for this. Thanks for your help!